# How to capture details of an aborted process into a logfile

Tags: linux, process, daemon

A daemon is started and running under Debian until it randomly crashes. I found out that it sometimes aborts due to an assertion which is shown if the process is running in foreground, like:

> /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:424: T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = libcage::dht::query]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
>   Aborted

The exitcode is 134, but how to save the more detailed error description (there could be many different) into a logfile for a later analysis, if the process is running in background?

"2> /log/mylogfile" is writing nothing and "> /log/mylogfile" is writing the process output ignoring the abort message. Also in "dmesg" or "kern.log" is nothing.

Comment: If this is on RHEL or CentOS 6 or 7 (or probably other derivatives), [`abrtd`](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ABRT) may already be catching it. Look in `/var/spool/abrt` or `/var/tmp/abrt`.

Comment: Thanks, but nope, both directories are empty in Debian

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to see what is wrong. It will log the syscalls used, signals, and return values.

Just `strace -v -s 256 -D -o /tmp/daemonlog daemonapp` and you can see execution details.

> -v: print environment
>
> -s string size: 256 bytes
>
> -D run strace as detached granchild
>
> -o logfile

Comment: It looks like it is creating a huge logfile for debugging purpose - not feasible for normal daemon running on productive machines...

Comment: Yes, the intention is to create a logfile for debugging. You can pair it with logrotate and save only the last 10Mb or so. Analyse the logs when there's an error and restart the daemon without strace later.

Answer (score -1):

If your daemon uses 'bash script', add "set -x" in the beginning of the script and start your process again and see

Comment: It will not help, it's not a script error, it's a program error.

Comment: Yes, it's a native binary executable compiled out of c++ code. so it will not allow bash commands :-(